# How to upload file using a post request in the node http library?

Tags: node.js, http

From the Node.js http library docs:

```
http.request() returns an instance of the http.ClientRequest class. 
The ClientRequest instance is a writable stream. If one needs to upload a file 
with a POST request, then write to the ClientRequest object.
```

However I'm unsure how to leverage this in my current code:

```
var post_data = querystring.stringify({
    api_key: fax.api_key,
    api_secret: fax.api_secret_key,
    to: fax.fax_number,
    filename: ""
});

var options = {
    host: p_url.hostname.toString(),
    path: p_url.path.toString(),
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'Content-Length': post_data.length
    }
};

var postReq = http.request(options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
          console.log('Response: ' + chunk);
    });
});

postReq.write(post_data);
postReq.end();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you have a writable stream, you can use the `write()`, `end()` and `pipe()` methods on it. Therefore, you can just open a resource, and pipe it to the writable stream:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var stream = fs.createReadStream('./file');
stream.pipe(postReq);
```

Or something like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var stream = fs.createReadStream('./file');

stream.on('data', function(data) {
  postReq.write(data);
});

stream.on('end', function() {
  postReq.end();
});
```

Comment: but wait.. isn't the `data` the request body? How can i get file/image AND use the body parameters( my form data)?