# How to send a file inside a request in Node.js using the http(s) module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I need to send a file as part of a `POST` request in Node.js and I don't want to use other packages or external libraries but plain `http` (`https`) module, part of the standard Node.js API.

#### From the Node.js doc, an example

[This example](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http) in the Node.js doc, hints about what I want to achieve:

```
const postData = querystring.stringify({'msg': 'Hello World!'});

const options = {
  hostname: 'http://localhost',
  port: 8080,
  path: '/upload',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(postData)
  }
};

const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log(`STATUS: ${res.statusCode}`);
  console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(res.headers)}`);
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', (chunk) => {
    console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
  });
  res.on('end', () => {
    console.log('No more data in response.');
  });
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
});

// Write data to request body
req.write(postData);
req.end();
```

#### What I want

This example is very close to what I want to achieve, the only difference is in the very first lines:

```
const postData = querystring.stringify({'msg': 'Hello World!'}); // <== I want to send a file
```

Instead of sending a string, I want to send a file. The doc page says that it should be possible:

> `http.request()` returns an instance of the `http.ClientRequest` class. The `ClientRequest` instance is a **writable stream**. If one needs to upload a file with a `POST` request, then write to the `ClientRequest` object.

How can I do this?

---

#### Attempts

I have tried:

```
clientRequest.write(fs.createReadStream("C:/Users/public/myfile.txt"));
clientRequest.end();
```

But I get this error:

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be one of type string or Buffer. Received type object

Comment: @LawrenceCherone No unfortunately because it uses the (deprecated) module `request` and not `http`.

Comment: Ok this one, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936561/how-to-upload-file-using-a-post-request-in-the-node-http-library the idea is the same, load file into buffer you cant use a stream.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Yes... it does I think :)

Comment: How is it I could not find it!!! I have been searching in StackOverflow for 2 hours for a similar question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're using the streams correctly. 
Try this:

```
fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(req);
```